# Angular: Create a directive to animate an element

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

I want to create a directive that adds some animations to the host element. I want to keep the animations, states and logics within this directive, without any modification to the host.

Is it possible to achieve this through Angular's [animation system](https://angular.io/guide/animations)?

The first issue I encounter is that I can't define triggers in a directive like this:

```
@Directive({
    animations:[...]
})
```

`@Directive` doesn't accept `animations:[...]`. Why? I believe this is a legit use case of directives.

Any idea?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9947

Comment: An open issue, but not much movement on it. The thread has some workarounds that you could consider

Comment: maybe use a component instead, with <ng-content></ng-content> as template.

Comment: That changes the HTML structure so modifications to other elements, especially styles, may be needed, which is not ideal.